# How to make title of listoffigures and listoftables uppercase in text and lowercase in tableofcontent?

Tags: table-of-contents

How to make tittle of listoffigures and listoftables uppercase in text and lowercase in tableofcontent?
Here is my configure file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {img/} }
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\titleformat
{\section} % command
[hang] % shape
{\bfseries\Large} % format
{\thesection. } % label
{0pt} % sep
{\MakeTextUppercase} % before-code
[] % after-code
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{12pt}{6pt}

\titleformat
{\subsection} % command
[hang] % shape
{\large\bfseries\itshape} % format
{\thesubsection. } % label
{0em} % sep
{} % before-code
[] % after-code
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{12pt}{6pt}

\titleformat
{\subsubsection} % command
[hang] % shape
{\large\itshape} % format
{\thesubsubsection. } % label
{0em} % sep
{} % before-code
[] % after-code
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{12pt}{6pt}

\titleformat
{\chapter} % command
[hang] % shape
{\bfseries\Large} % format
{\thechapter. } % label
{0pt} % sep
{\MakeTextUppercase} % before-code
[] % after-code
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{12pt}{6pt}

\usepackage[]{algorithmic}

\floatname{algorithm}{Procedure}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Wejście:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Wyjście:}}

\captionsetup[table]{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false, format=hang}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\raggedright}{}{}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}
\frenchspacing

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\usepackage{uarial}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}  
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}

\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\newpage\stdsection}


\usepackage{polski}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{2} 

\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}


\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfoot[C]{\sffamily\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\titlecontents{section}
[0em]             % left margin
{\vspace{0 pt }}                   % above code
{%                  % numbered format
{\thecontentslabel. }%
}%
{}         % unnumbered format
{\enspace\titlerule*{.} \contentspage}         % filler-page-format, e.g dots

% indented subsection (in toc)
\titlecontents{subsection}
[1em]             % left margin
{\vspace{0 pt }}                   % above code
{%                  % numbered format
{\thecontentslabel. }%
}%
{}         % unnumbered format
{ \enspace\titlerule*{.}\contentspage}         % filler-page-format

% indented subsection (in toc)
\titlecontents{subsubsection}
[3em]             % left margin
{\vspace{0 pt }}                   % above code
{%                  % numbered format
{\thecontentslabel. }%
}%
{}         % unnumbered format
{ \enspace\titlerule*{.}\contentspage}         % filler-page-format

\pagestyle{plain}
```

I am using Overleaf to compile this, here is link to my project:
https://www.overleaf.com/5613989qpysrv#/18155123/

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose. Also, please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. This will help us help you!

Comment: 95 % of the packages are not needed here and the stuff is not compilable at all. Using `tocloft` and `titlesec`together is no good idea

Comment: I am using Overleaf to compile this, here is link to my project: https://www.overleaf.com/5613989qpysrv#/18155123/

Comment: to make this question relevant for other users, a **minimal** working example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) would be needed. Linking to your overleaf-project is not really helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the way the chapter appears in the TOC with the option:

`\chapter[toc version]{doc version}`

you can also define a name then make it uppercase using `\MakeUppercase`